# MailKit not picking up "Auto-Submitted: auto-replied" header

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I'm reading messages using MailKit but I can't read the `Auto-Submitted: auto-replied` header for some reason. Other headers are read without a problem. Has anyone else experienced this?

Code for getting emails:

```
var inbox = imapClient.Inbox;
inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

var uids = inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);

return uids.Select(id => new ImapMessage()
{
    ImapId = id.Id,
    MimeMessage = inbox.GetMessage(id)
});
```

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Message:

[image]

Same message seen through Outlook, here the `Auto-Submitted: auto-replied` header is present.

[image]

Comment: Follow the instructions in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) on getting a protocol log. Does this `Auto-Submitted` header exist in the response sent by the server? If not, you've found the problem.

Comment: @jstedfast Thanks! Turned out the header was not present in the mail read. Great feature with logging `var client = new ImapClient (new ProtocolLogger ("imap.log"));`